# QEMU Guest IO Errors with Raw Image Once a Week

Tags: kvm, qemu, virsh

I am seeing a strange issue with virtual machines running on my server where once a week they will stall. Every Monday Morning PDT, the services running on the VMs will freeze up (for example, nginx, nextcloud). In that state, sometimes I can ssh into the VMs, but sometimes no access at all (connection will close as soon as it opens). If I can login, I can't even reboot from within the VM because I get a file IO error. A quick virsh destroy and virsh start of each vm (or a bare metal reboot) fixes the issue. And it always seems to happen on the same day of the week for all of the VMs. Most of them run Ubuntu, but one runs Centos with the same symptoms. The host OS is Intel Clear Linux (automatic updates turned off).

All of the VMs use a raw qemu image for their disk. The bare metal filesystem is XFS and the VMs use EXT4. However, because this happens once a week at the same time, I am inclined to think this is some sort of update checking from QEMU or the VMs themselves. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: `cron` job on the host?

Comment: No cron jobs on host

Comment: I would look at daemons running on the host, paying particular attention to anything storage (i.e. S.M.A.R.T.) or RAID related. I would try to get a `dmesg` output from any guests that I'm able to `ssh` into, and the host as well. And I would look into QEMU logging options (`-d` and `-D`).